# Socket closed Exception and EOF exception

Tags: java, serversocket

I have been working on a basic text transmitting code in Java and I'm unable to understand the error in my code.

Both server side program and client side program have same code for sending and receiving.

Server:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(44444);
System.out.println("Waiting...");
Socket s = ss.accept();
System.out.println("Connected!\n\n");

DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Thread send = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
   public void run()
   {
      try
      {
         String tx = "";
         while(!tx.equalsIgnoreCase("Over"))
         {
            tx = br.readLine();
            if(tx.equals(""))
               continue;
            dout.writeUTF(tx);
            dout.flush();
         }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
};

Thread receive = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
   public void run()
   {
      try
      {
         String rx = "";               
         while(!rx.equalsIgnoreCase("Over"))
         {
            rx = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Server: " + rx);
         }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
});

send.start();
receive.start();

if(!send.isAlive()||!receive.isAlive())
{
   din.close();
   dout.close();
   ss.close();
}
```

Client:

```
Socket s = new Socket("localhost",44444);
System.out.println("Connected!\n\n");

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Thread send = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
   public void run()
   {
      try
      {
         String tx = "";
         while(!tx.equalsIgnoreCase("Over"))
         {
            tx = br.readLine();
            if(tx.equals(""))
               continue;
            dout.writeUTF(tx);
            dout.flush();
         }
      }
      catch(Exception e)//Itha catch zala exception
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      System.out.println("a");

    }
});

Thread receive = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
   public void run()
   {
      try
      {
         String rx = "";               
         while(!rx.equalsIgnoreCase("Over"))
         {
            rx = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Server: " + rx);
         }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
});

send.start();
receive.start();     

if(!send.isAlive()||!receive.isAlive())
{
   din.close();
   dout.close();
   s.close();
}
```

The exception is on "din.readUTF();"
The message is supposed to be transmitted but it's just throwing EOFexception and SocketException: Socket Closed.

Edit: Uploaded full code

Comment: Can you send the rest of the code (that includes initializing the `Socket`)?

Comment: a stack trace would be helpful or line numbers or something.. i'm not a java programmer but my guess, if i had to guess, would be that the line `rx = din.readUTF()`. if this is a non-blocking operation then it could be the' cause of your error because 'right away' it's reading EOF or somethin'. just a guess tho.

Comment: Your server and client will have different code. Look at a tutorial on writing a client and a server socket